# I am facing an error in solving mixed content in Wordpress even after using better search and replace plugging? {Wordpress}

Tags: wordpress, mixed-content

[image]

I have tried using better search and replace plugin to replace all http:// url's tp https://. But, still there is an error with the media files as per the attachment. Please help me on the same!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to make your website Https// friendly is to install plugin "Really Simple SSL" it will change all your http into https and you will not have mix content.